# DPDA for language $L=\{a,b\}^* \setminus a^nb^n \setminus b^na^n$

Tags: pushdown-automata

How to construct DPDA for the following language $L=\{a,b\}^* \setminus a^nb^n  \setminus  b^na^n $

$L_1 = \{a,b\}^* \setminus a^nb^n =\{a^i b^j \, | \, i>j\}\,\cup\,\{a^i b^j\ \ | \ i<j\}\,\cup\,(a+b)^* b (a+b)^* a (a+b)^*$.

At this step I got stuck. What is next? How to express additional difference $b^na^n$?

Comment: We are looking to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future.  "Here is an exercise-style task, I have no idea how to start, can you solve it for me?" typically is not a good fit for this site.  I suggest you refer to https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755, try to identify what is preventing you from solving it, generalize your difficulty, and ask a conceptual question that is likely to be useful to others (even if they aren't looking at exactly the same task as you).

Comment: @D.W. Corrected, you can remove your downvote.

Comment: @cs_student how is it corrected? "/" mean?

Comment: @AlokMaity look closely. Second sentence and explanation after it.

Comment: Please use standard notation for languages.  $/ a^n b^n$ is not a standard notation you will find in a textbook.  It appears to be some kind of shorthand; please avoid shorthand and use standard mathematical notation.

Comment: Edited to replace forward slash with \setminus.

Answer (score 1):

Given $L=(a+b)^*- a^nb^n-b^na^n$ which could be written as $L=(a+b)^*- (a^nb^n \cup b^na^n)=(a+b)^* \bigcap (a^nb^n \cup b^na^n)^\complement= 
(a+b)^* \bigcap \{(a+b)^*-(a^nb^n \cup b^na^n)\}=(a+b)^*\bigcap(\{a^mb^n | m\neq n\}\cup\{b^ma^n | m\neq n\}\cup a(a+b)^*a\cup b(a+b)^*b \cup (ab)^*b \cup (ba) ^*a)
=\{a^mb^n | m\neq n\}\cup\{b^ma^n | m\neq n\}\cup a(a+b)^*a\cup b(a+b)^*b\cup (ab)^*b \cup (ba) ^*a,$

from here you could make $DPDA$ easily.

Comment: So abba not in the final language? Why not?